# ethernet(eno3) unmanaged on ubuntu server 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, ethernet

I need solution to ethernet(eno3) unmanaged on ubuntu server 20.04, the pc is blade server could not browse internet on firefox browser.
But other app like anydesk could connect internet(lan)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.